# Merge [photo-editing] and [image-editing]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

This is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) for reasons listed in answers below:

---

[image-editing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-editing)  [photo-editing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-editing)

They are both well used tags, but they seemingly mean the same thing.

Which one should be a synonym of the other?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

To be pedantic: every photo is an image, but not every image is a photo. As long as they are correctly applied, I do see a use for both of these tags. There are certainly techniques that only (or mostly) apply to [photo-editing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-editing) and not to [image-editing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-editing) in general.

Comment: I wrote a tag usage guidance for [image-editing], since there was none

Answer (score 4):

Illustrator, Inkscape, Xara, Sketch, et. al. create images, but do not create photos. Heck even Photoshop ***creates*** images not photos. Only camera's create photos.

You can't call an icon a photo.... You can't call an Illustration a photo.. that sort of thing.

Comment: Would that mean that mean in Photoshop a photo imported, modified, and exported would no longer be a photo?

Comment: @LateralTerminal Photoshop *can* manipulate photos, yes. But it doesn't *exclusively* manipulate photos. Looking at things like Lightroom, which is really a strict *photo* editing application, Photoshop is more versatile and *image* creation is just as likely as *photo* manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Webster defines it as

- > Definition of photo plural photos : photograph
- > photograph : a picture or likeness obtained by photography
- > Definition of photography : the art or process of producing images by
  >   the action of radiant energy and especially light on a sensitive
  >   surface (such as film or an optical sensor)

So no, it's not the same as a picture it has to be taken from a camera.

**The saved file might still be considered a photo not an image.**

**A photo modified and saved in Photoshop would be considered a photo too**